# AngularJS directive design patterns for a sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angularJS to create a simple side menu. I have the following two options for its directive design but cannot decide which one is better:

**Option 1**

The HTML markup:

```
<sidebar title="Sidebar Heading">
  <sidebar-element name="Heading">Description</sidebar-element>
  ...
</sidebar>
```

**Option 2**

The HTML markup:

```
<sidebar>Sidebar Heading</sidebar>
```

And, the data is coming directly from the controller:

```
$scope.sidebarElements=[{name:'Head 1', description:'Description 1', isActive:true}];
```

Consider that the data is coming to me from the server in JSON.

If I go with option 2, I can pass the data directly to the controller.

If I go with option 1, I would have to do a `<sidebar-element ng-repeat='element in elements' ...>` in it, and then pass on the data to it. Option 1 seems 'better designed' somehow but I don't know if I should build another layer of abstraction this way when it is not especially required.

Which one of the two would be better and why?

I have just started to work with AngularJS and am trying to find the right way to 'think in AngularJS'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how extensible you need to make this design. If you want to make this design to work as option1 in future, then only you should go for it, because it is also going to consume more time to put extra piece of code.

If you want to go with highly extensible approach you should create  directive and also the  directive which will create  collection using controller data. **This (Option1) will allow user to use the combination of both the directives to get the menu with static or dynamic data.**
If you decide to go with option1, this link will be useful [LINK] : http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/
[It has live example] : http://jsbin.com/acibiv/3/edit

**If your data is always coming from json (controller data) and there will never be the need to add  from html (static ) then you just go with option2.**

**I think as you are starting, you should go for option2 (Less reusable but easier as compared).**

**About directive naming**
I think sidebar may contain other elements (other than menu).  So naming should tell that it is menu.